# Need help replicating this unity transformation in raylib

Tags: unity, transformation, raylib

i was hoping i could get some advice on a transformation im trying to perform on some billboards. i have a billboard in 3d space thats being rotated a long the view matrix's up + right axis, against a quaternion (in this case, its a quaternion of (0, 0.6, 0, -0.8) (Euler angles: 0, 290, 0).

Visibly the rotation appears applied but it looks like the models are missing a translation in order to mimic the output im getting from unity. anyone got any advice? Here's a visual aid. (bottom is expected, top is current in raylib. notice how the top should be translated roughly 0.25% of the width of the figure)

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:
This is the custom draw code for the billboard I wrote in raylib:

```
void Draw3DBillboardRec(Camera camera, Texture2D texture, Rectangle source, Vector3 position, Vector2 size, Quaternion targetQuat, Color tint)
{
    Vector2 sizeRatio = { size.x, size.y };
    
    Quaternion tQuat = targetQuat;

    Matrix matView = MatrixLookAt(camera.position, camera.target, camera.up);

    Vector3 right = { matView.m0, matView.m4, matView.m8 };
    Vector3 up = { matView.m1, matView.m5, matView.m9 };
    
    // rotate both up + right vectors to achieve same effect like unity
    up = Vector3RotateByQuaternion(up, tQuat);
    right = Vector3RotateByQuaternion(right, tQuat);
    
    Vector3 rightScaled = Vector3Scale(right, sizeRatio.x/2);
    Vector3 upScaled = Vector3Scale(up, sizeRatio.y/2);

    Vector3 p1 = Vector3Add(rightScaled, upScaled);
    Vector3 p2 = Vector3Subtract(rightScaled, upScaled);

    Vector3 topLeft = Vector3Scale(p2, -1);
    Vector3 topRight = p1;
    Vector3 bottomRight = p2;
    Vector3 bottomLeft = Vector3Scale(p1, -1);

    // Translate points to the draw center (position)
    topLeft = Vector3Add(topLeft, position);
    topRight = Vector3Add(topRight, position);
    bottomRight = Vector3Add(bottomRight, position);
    bottomLeft = Vector3Add(bottomLeft, position);

    rlCheckRenderBatchLimit(4);

    rlSetTexture(texture.id);

    rlBegin(RL_QUADS);
        rlColor4ub(tint.r, tint.g, tint.b, tint.a);

        // Bottom-left corner for texture and quad
        rlTexCoord2f((float)source.x/texture.width, (float)source.y/texture.height);
        rlVertex3f(topLeft.x, topLeft.y, topLeft.z);

        // Top-left corner for texture and quad
        rlTexCoord2f((float)source.x/texture.width, (float)(source.y + source.height)/texture.height);
        rlVertex3f(bottomLeft.x, bottomLeft.y, bottomLeft.z);

        // Top-right corner for texture and quad
        rlTexCoord2f((float)(source.x + source.width)/texture.width, (float)(source.y + source.height)/texture.height);
        rlVertex3f(bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y, bottomRight.z);

        // Bottom-right corner for texture and quad
        rlTexCoord2f((float)(source.x + source.width)/texture.width, (float)source.y/texture.height);
        rlVertex3f(topRight.x, topRight.y, topRight.z);
    rlEnd();

    rlSetTexture(0);
}
```

The following are the parameter variables:

camera up: 0,1,0
camera target: 0,0,0
camera position: 0,0,-10

position: -0.08, -0.6, 0
size: 5,5
targetQuat: 0, -0.6, 0, -0.8

Comment: Can you share a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of this problem? That is, all code and instructions a reader would need to follow to reproduce this problem starting from a new, empty project?

Comment: @DMGregory I edited the description :)

Comment: In future, please edit your existing question rather than posting a duplicate.